# I want to Scroll down android app page but scroll only works once

Tags: javascript, node.js, appium, webdriver-io, appium-android

```
scrollDown() {
driver.touchAction([
    {action: 'press', x: 466, y: 1702},
    {action: 'moveTo', x: 483, y: 277},
    'release'
  ]); }
```

this scrollDown only works once. But when I call it again nothing happens. 
I need to Scroll two times and then have setValues and then have to scroll down again. But it only works once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue on native context of my hybrid app. I have used below api to scroll. I had to use it five times based on the amount of scroll it does on each instance. This is equivalent of down arrow key.

```
browser.longPressKeyCode(20);
```

More information [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html).
Hope this helps.

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you soo much @Raju.. It's working perfectly fine for me too.